# How to make fasttext's get_sentence_vector vector larger?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, fasttext

I have trained in unsupervised way fasttext model and now I am using `get_sentence_vector()` function to get vectors of sentences. But it outputs vectors with length 100. How could I make those vectors longer (300 values)? Is there any hyper parameter for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/unsupervised-tutorial.html#advanced-readers-playing-with-the-parameters), if you want vectors with size 300, you have to train your unsupervised model, by setting `dim` parameter to 300.

```
model = fasttext.train_unsupervised(YOUR_DATA, dim=300)
```

**Once the model has been trained** and learned a linguistic representation from your data, as far as I know **there is no way to increase the size of the generated vectors**.